# MVC5 how to display image from database depending on selected value from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, database, image, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to display a single from database depending on selected value from dropdownlist. Currently I'm trying to use

```
    <img id="preview" src="@Url.Action("getImage", "Home",new { id = item.Id })" /> 

    public string getImage(int id)
    {
        Gifts img = db.gifts.Find(id);
        Byte[] imgByte = img.gift_image;
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(img.gift_image);
        var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64);
        return imgSrc;
    }
```

however nothing is displaying
the following works but it displays all images and I only want to display the one linked to the selected item from the database

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {


        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.gift_image);
        var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
        <img src='@imgSrc' />


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How is working your dropdown ?

```
document.getElementById("preview").src=imgSrc;
```

should load your image if your dropdown can set your imgSrc variable.